# MSE on cross validation of MLP

Tags: time-series

Why is the value of MSE in cross-validation is always less than 1 in the MSE values of the hidden nodes selected by the MLP function.

[image]

This is the result of the code

```
fit2 <- mlp(fit, auto.hd.type = "cv")
fit2$MSEH
```

The values of my input have a mean of 9000.

Further, the MSE of my model is this
[image]

Comment: No. I added more info in here

Comment: In that case, please edit your old post instead of asking the same question again for that post has already been viewed and commented by others.